Unexpected behaviour when trying to implement a queue with two stacks in C
I am dealing with a very popular problem of implementing a queue with two stacks and doing it in C language as it gives me an excuse to brush up my knowledge of structs and pointers .
I have created two stack variables with the help of struct , st1 and st2 respectively . I push the elements into st1 for enqueue operation and for dequeue , elements from st1 are popped and pushed simultaneously into st2 . After popping st2 , the elements are again transferred back into st1 (I know this is redundant but this is not the problem I am facing) . All of this has been implemented with respective functions in a switch case in main() .
The bug is , while invoking the dequeue operation , the 1st element of st1 gets mysteriously overridden by some other value .
Here is the complete code :
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct stack
{
    char name[5] ;
    int top ; 
    int *a ; 
}Stack ;
int n ; 
int main()
{
    void push(Stack*,int) ; 
    int delete(Stack*,Stack*) ;
    void display(Stack*) ;
    printf("Enter the size of the queue: ") ;
    scanf("%d",&n) ;
    Stack st1,st2 ; 
    st1.a = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int)) ;
    st1.top = -1 ; 
    st2 = st1 ;
    strcpy(st1.name,"st1") ;
    strcpy(st2.name,"st2") ;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter 1. to insert.\nEnter 2. to delete.\nEnter 3. to display.\nEnter anything else to exit.\n") ; 
        char c ; 
        int e ;
        scanf(" %c",&c) ; 
        switch(c)
        {
            case '1': 
            printf("Enter the no. to be inserted: ") ;
            scanf("%d",&e) ; 
            push(&st1,e) ;
            break ; 
            case '2' :
            e = delete(&st1,&st2) ; 
            printf("%d got deleted.\n",e) ;
            break ; 
            case '3' : 
            display(&st1) ;
            break ; 
            default : 
            free(st1.a) ; 
            free(st2.a) ; 
            return 0 ;
        }
    }
}
int delete(Stack *st1,Stack *st2)
{
    void push(Stack*,int) ; 
    int pop(Stack*) ;
    while(st1->top!=-1)
    push(st2,pop(st1)) ;

    int e = pop(st2) ; 

    while(st2->top!=-1)
    push(st1,pop(st2)) ;

    return e ;
}
void push(Stack *st,int e)
{
    void display(Stack*) ;
    printf("Operations on %s begin: \n",st->name) ;
    printf("Currently %s:\n",st->name) ;
    display(st) ;
    st->top++ ; 
    if(st->top==n)
    {
        printf("Queue full.\n") ;
        st->top-- ;
        return ; 
    }
    st->a[st->top] = e ;
    printf("After operations , %s:\n",st->name) ;
    display(st) ;
    printf("Operations on %s end.\n\n",st->name) ;
}
int pop(Stack *st)
{
    void display(Stack*) ;
    printf("Operations on %s begin: \n",st->name) ;
    display(st) ;
    if(st->top==-1)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty.\n") ;
        return -1 ;
    }
    int e = st->a[st->top] ; 
    st->top-- ; 
    printf("After operations , %s:\n",st->name) ;
    display(st) ;
    printf("Operations on %s end.\n\n",st->name) ;
    return e ;
}
void display(Stack *st)
{
    if(st->top==-1)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty.\n") ;
        return ;
    }
    int i ;
    for(i=0;i<=st->top;i++)
    printf("%d ",st->a[i]) ;
    printf("\n") ;
}

As you can see , I have written printf() statements for debugging .
And here is the output so you can see the bug :
Enter the size of the queue: 5
Enter 1. to insert.
Enter 2. to delete.
Enter 3. to display.
Enter anything else to exit.
1
Enter the no. to be inserted: 1
Operations on st1 begin: 
Currently st1:
Queue is empty.
After operations , st1:
1 
Operations on st1 end.

Enter 1. to insert.
Enter 2. to delete.
Enter 3. to display.
Enter anything else to exit.
1
Enter the no. to be inserted: 2
Operations on st1 begin: 
Currently st1:
1 
After operations , st1:
1 2 
Operations on st1 end.

Enter 1. to insert.
Enter 2. to delete.
Enter 3. to display.
Enter anything else to exit.
2
Operations on st1 begin: 
1 2 
After operations , st1:
1 
Operations on st1 end.

Operations on st2 begin: 
Currently st2:
Queue is empty.
After operations , st2:
2 
Operations on st2 end.

Operations on st1 begin: 
2 
After operations , st1:
Queue is empty.
Operations on st1 end.

Operations on st2 begin: 
Currently st2:
2 
After operations , st2:
2 2 
Operations on st2 end.

Operations on st2 begin: 
2 2 
After operations , st2:
2 
Operations on st2 end.

Operations on st2 begin: 
2 
After operations , st2:
Queue is empty.
Operations on st2 end.

Operations on st1 begin: 
Currently st1:
Queue is empty.
After operations , st1:
2 
Operations on st1 end.

2 got deleted.
Enter 1. to insert.
Enter 2. to delete.
Enter 3. to display.
Enter anything else to exit.

You can see when I invoke dequeue operation , after popping 2 from st1 and pushing it into st2 , the 0th index of st1 gets changed from 1 to 2 .
I have been baffled by this for quite some time now . I thought pointers were the problem , so I removed all of them and did the same thing but passed the stack variables by value . When I did that , there was an even bigger problem , each time I inserted a value it somehow got removed automatically . So when I tried to insert the next time , the previous insertion had disappeared .
I feel there are some fundamental problems causing these issues that need to be addressed to make the code work like it should .

You can't use stacks for queues. Queues are FIFO, stacks are LIFO. I also don't understand the point of using two stacks.

Function declarations should be at top-level, not nested inside other functions.

st1 and st2 are using the same memory for a, because st2 = st1 just copies the a pointer, it doesn't make a copy of the memory it points to. So you need to allocate them separately.
    Stack st1; 
    st1.a = malloc(n*sizeof(int)) ;
    st1.top = -1 ; 
    Stack st2; 
    st2.a = malloc(n*sizeof(int)) ;
    st2.top = -1 ; 

Also, in C you shouldn't cast the result of malloc().

Thank you sir , for your swift response. The code works as expected . Silly errors on my part .
